# How to scrape contents from Multiple different domain websites using Beautifulsoup?

Tags: web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pagination, scrape

Actually i developed the full code for scrape the content from single website with the help of Beautifulsoup (*it contains the pagination as well*), which is used to scrape the conference details. But now, **I need to scrape the details from multiple conference websites**. The `"class"` names and `<div>` tags and etc were different for each websites. So how can i manage to scrape the details without develop the multiple scripts?

Comment: You answered your own question with `The "class" names and <div> tags and etc were different for each websites.` You can't (unless each website has exact same structure), which is unlikely and you will need different scripts/functions for different sites. Secondly, do these websites have an api? That could make it easier to develop. Share a few of the sites/urls and I can look. What was the orginal site you scraped?

Comment: i scraped whole conference details from https://www.himss.org/global-conference/schedule

Comment: And what's an example of another conference site?

Comment: Another link is : https://www.siop.org/Annual-Conference/Conference-Schedule

Comment: ok. So ya. You will need to develop different scripts/functions to parse each site, as they are completely different. For example, the second site uses `<table>` tags. The first one doesn't.

Comment: then fine. i used separate